# How to log error on sentry if using remove-console?

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, console.log, sentry

I removed all `console.log` in my web application when building production version. But, I would like to send some logs to my sentry if errors occur.

Since setting remove console in `babel-config.js`, my sentry can not get logs.

```
const removeConsolePlugin = []
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  removeConsolePlugin.push('transform-remove-console')
}

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ],
  plugins: removeConsolePlugin
}
```

How do I send log to sentry if remove-console is necessary on production?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add onto sentry reports by using breadcrumbs.
That will let you add much richer data to the reports as well.

[See Sentry's breadcrumb function](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/enriching-events/breadcrumbs/#manual-breadcrumbs). Note the support for the `data` field, which can hold any data you'd like to add onto the report.

Beyond that, the babel transform you are using also has some options that may help you. [See their README.md](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console#via-babelrc-recommended), you can keep `console.error` and `console.warn`, those will then still end up in Sentry reports.